# Wine no longer installs & throws errors on installation

Tags: package-management, wine

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 and every time I try to install Wine, I get an error that says: "libgudev-1.0-0 i386 1:233 1:233-1 is not (yet) available" and then goes on to tell me some IP address is forbidden. It installed just fine on another of my computers only a month or two ago. I am getting this on a few other apps I have tried to install too, such as Freecad.

As a further question why does the Ubuntu package manager lag so much and hang on searches the majority of the time. It seems very clunky and dodgy! It's driving me insane...

Comment: I would `sudo apt update` and read the messages provided.  Are you using the official Ubuntu archive? or a mirror?  Who provides that mirror? as maybe you would be better on another? using another source.  We cannot read the messages, being limited to only what you provide for us, but mirrors available can be viewed at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors  or for more details (inc. how to change) you can see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Changing servers seemed to fix both the install problem and the lagging problem... for a while. The install now doesn't work for completely different reasons and the lagging is back... but changing servers DID fix this particular problem.